# returns NaN by ++ and --

Tags: javascript

here's two buttons, one decreases other increases both per one.

```js
function inc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("num");
  ++i;
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = i;
}

function dec() {
  var i = document.getElementById("num");
  i--;
  if (i <= 0) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="disp">
  <div id="num">0</div>
</div>

<button onclick="dec()" class="but">-</button>
<button onclick="inc()" class="but">+</button>
```

but this returns NaN; what can I do?

Comment: As the method name suggests, `getElementById` will return the element of the element with the specified id. You need to obtain the text within the element, this can be done multiple ways, such as using `.textContent`.

Comment: You are facing this issue because `getElementById` method returns **Element object **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the text of the html element for example like this:

```js
function inc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("num").innerHTML;
  ++i;
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = i;
}

function dec() {
  var i = document.getElementById("num").innerHTML;
  i--;
  if (i <= 0) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="disp">
  <div id="num">0</div>
</div>

<button onclick="dec()" class="but">-</button>
<button onclick="inc()" class="but">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){

  $('#add').on('click',add);
  $('#sub').on('click',remove);

});


function add(){

  var input = $('#Quantity'),
      value = input.val();
      
  input.val(++value);
  
  if(value > 0){
    $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
  }

}


function remove(){

   var input = $('#Quantity'),
       value = input.val();
      
   if(value > 0){
     input.val(--value);
   }else{
     $('#sub').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="disp">
 <input id="Quantity" disable="true">
</div>

<button id="sub" class="but">-</button>
<button id="add" class="but">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get the html of num:

```
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value.

You are dealing with text in that element so you can try  textContent also

```
<script>
  function inc()
   {
     var i = document.getElementById("num").textContent;
     console.log(i);
     ++i;
     document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = i;
   }

   function dec() {
     var i = document.getElementById("num").textContent;
     i--;
     if (i <= 0) 
       {
          i = 0;
       } else {
          document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = i;
        }
      }
</script>
```